# Do for loops work in CasperJS for waiting for something?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I want my program to check to see if something loaded every 500 milliseconds until it finds it.  waitForSelector doesn't work (don't ask; it just doesn't).  However, `casper.exists("css3path")` does find it.

Here's my code, I don't know if I'm just making some stupid mistake on a really basic level that I'm not seeing, or whether for loops don't work, or what the problem is.

```
casper.then(function(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        if(casper.exists('#bookmark-FSE')){
            i = 100;
        } else{
            casper.wait(500)
            this.echo(i + 'seconds')
        };
    };
});
casper.then(function(){
    //rest of my code
```

I know the error is in here, because if I replace the whole thing with a dumb wait(time, function(){ it works.  The problem is that the time it takes varies greatly (3->6 seconds) and I'd like to cut it shorter.  When I try to run it I get a syntax error message.  Just for reference, I'm using phantomjs version 1.9.2.  What am I doing wrong, is there any other way to do it (no waitFors are working)?

Comment: You could reimplement wait for with wait() and exists(), but there is some other problem that needs fixing. I mean it will work in the same way that wait for() does.

Comment: would the for loop idea work though?  why is it giving me a syntax error?  Is it just a stupid mistake, or, do for loops in general not work in casperjs?

Comment: No, you can't use any loops. You have to use recursion.

Comment: Does `casper.exists()` find the element twice? `var e1 = casper.exists(path); var e2 = casper.exists(path); casper.echo(e1 + " " + e2);` ; I don't mean with the code above, but with your other simple `wait(time)` code.

Comment: We gave it an id and the path is now different (no more nth child).  Does this change anything (waitforselector still couldn't find it)?

Comment: Yes, this confirms that it is not the nth-child bug at play here. I have no idea what's the problem here.

Comment: haha no problem.  I might just end up using multiple if/else loops with wait(500)s in between.  It's not elegant but whatever works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use any loop to wait for something in JavaScript. Since JavaScript has no blocking `sleep()` function or something like that, it is not possible to check for some condition and wait in a loop.

All `then*` and `wait*` functions are asynchronous step functions in CasperJS. It means that by calling then, the matching step is only scheduled in CasperJS's asynchronous environment.

You can recreate `waitFor()` easily with CasperJS like this:

```
casper.myWaitFor = function(test, then, onTimeout, timeout){
    timeout = timeout || this.options.waitTimeout; // 5000
    return this.then(function(){
        if (test.call(this)) {
            if (then) {
                then.call(this);
            }
        }
        this.wait(500, function _then(){
            if (timeout - 500 > 0) {
                this.myWaitFor(test, then, onTimeout, timeout - 500);
            } else if (onTimeout) {
                onTimeout.call(this);
            } else {
                throw new CasperError("Waited without success");
            }
        });
    });
};

casper.myWaitForSelector = function(selector, then, onTimeout, timeout){
    return this.myWaitFor(function(){
        return this.exists(selector);
    }, then, onTimeout, timeout)
};
```

Use it like this:

```
casper.start(url)
    .then(function(){ /* do something */})
    .myWaitForSelector('#bookmark-FSE', function(){
        this.echo("success");
    })
    .run();
```

I doubt this will help you, but it's another implementation of `waitFor()`.

---

You get a syntax error, because there is no `int` in JavaScript. You probably meant `var`.